# How to store data in seperate memory mdoules

Tags: python, multithreading, memory, memory-management

I'm working on an image processing pipeline in Python and I'm using Cython for the main computation so that it can run really fast. From early benchmarks, I found a memory bottleneck where the code would not scale at all using multiple threads.

I revised the algorithm a bit to reduce the bandwidth required and now it scales to 2 cores (4 threads with hyperthreading) but it still becomes bottlenecked by memory bandwidth. You can find the different versions of the algorithm here if you are curious: https://github.com/2332575Y/

I have confirmed this by running the benchmark on an i7-6700HQ (scales to 4 threads), i5-7600K (scales to 2 threads (cores) as the i5 has no hyper-threading), and an R9-5950X (scales to 4 threads). Also despite the massive performance differences between these CPUs, the relative performance between them is exactly the same difference between the memory speeds. You can find the benchmarks performed by the 6700HQ here:
https://github.com/2332575Y/Retina-V3/blob/main/Untitled.ipynb

and the 5950x benchmarks are:
[image]
[image]
[image]

All of these benchmarks are performed without any manual memory management and since the overall size of the data is relatively small (120MB), I would assume python puts them on a single memory stick (all of the systems have dual-channel memory). I'm not sure if it is possible to somehow tell python to split the data and store it on different physical memory modules so that the algorithm can take advantage of the dual-channel memory. I tried googling ways to do this in C++ but that wasn't successful either. Is memory automatically managed by the OS or is it possible to do this?

P.S.: before you comment, I have made sure to split the inputs as evenly as possible. Also, the sampling algorithm is extremely simple (multiply and accumulate), so having a memory bottleneck is not an absurd concept (it is actually pretty common in image processing algorithms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS manages splitting the program virtual address space to the different physical addresses (Ram sticks, pagefile, etc) this is transparent to python or any programming language, all systems were already using both sticks for read and write.

The fact that both float64 and float32 have the same performance means each core cache is almost never used, so consider making better use of it in your algorithms, make your code more cache friendly.

While this may seem hard for a loop that just computes a multiplication, you can group computations to reduce the number of times you access the memory.

Edit: also consider shifting the work to the GPU or TPU as dedicated gpus are very good at convolutions, and have much faster memories.

Comment: That is what I assumed, but then how do memory benchmarking tools achieve correct results? If they're unable to perform transactions on all memory channels, the overall bandwidth can be wrong by a factor of 2 or 4.

Also, I'm aware of the fact that cache is mostly not used here (hence the memory bandwidth issue), but performing sparse convolutions is not a cache-friendly operation (each coefficient is only used once per sampling step), meaning this is the best result that feasibly can be achieved.

Comment: @OM222O consider using a gpu instead, gpu memories are much much faster, and do convolutions naturally.

Comment: I'm curious about the grouping of computations, do you have any examples/links I can have a look at? Also, a GPU version will be created later on using CUDA, but for the majority of applications (robotics), that's not a real option. I'm currently investigating using FPGAs (most likely with integer-only operations) with a custom high-bandwidth memory solution since FPGAs are smaller, cheaper, more power efficient, and also much more flexible for implementing these algorithms.

Comment: @OM222O it depends on what you are doing with the data after you do the computations, if you are doing more computations on it then maybe you can do those while you are already doing this first convolution, like if you are computing a kernel on the result you can almost "fuse" both kernels, but this depends on way too many factors, so it's impossible to get a "one size fits all" solution.

Comment: @OM222O also if you are reading it from a file, you can fuse the reading from file with the kernel calculation to not have to read the data again from memory to apply the kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is used as a framework and there are many possible uses for the result, so I'm not sure if it would be possible to combine operations. Maybe I can have a parser that generates and compiles the cython extension based on the defined pipeline? that seems like a lot of work for very little gains though. Using multiple memory channels seems like a low-hanging fruit for free performance, but the OS throws a wrench into that idea.
there is a code demo (and my master's dissertation) if you are curious: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cS8CaCAMZLrLR5CEfhuF_60VoeWWeB9U